# While trying to read ConnectionString value in C# .net 6.0 console app getting Object reference null error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a console application(.Net 6.0) with app.config file with following data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="ConnectionKey" connectionString="my connection value" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I am trying to read the connection string the following way but I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
 cnx = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionKey"].ConnectionString);
```

Is there something more I have to add? Or is there any other approach to read the connectionString value?

Update:

I have changed the app.config to appsettings.json with following code

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=_CHANGE_ME;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "MyConn": "my connection string"
}
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using an App.config file? .net 6 uses AppSettings.json be default

Comment: @scottdavidwalker I have changed it to appsettings.json. Can you please tell me how I can read that value in my code

Comment: @Jess please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: I think that the answer of @Rena should solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the connection string like below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string conn = _configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");
        var  cnx = new SqlConnection(conn);
        //do your stuff...
        return View();
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
      "MyConnection": "your connection string"        //focus here...
    }
}
```